# SQL Group by across columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I have a simple messaging-system, which messages now shall be grouped by subject. So the table looks like:

```
   id  | sender | recipient | subject
------------------------------------
    1  |    16  |     17    |  Hello   
    2  |    17  |     16    |  Hello   
    3  |    12  |     16    |  Hello
```

"sender" and "recipient " are id´s from a users table.

So the User shall see the messages grouped by subject, which is easy possibly by GROUP BY.

The Problem is that also messages are grouped, that have the same subject but other sender and recipients. Is it possible to group the messages just if sender and recipient are the same? In the example, the messages 1 and 2 should be grouped, but not 3. So I need to group across 2 columns.

Comment: a) what have you tried?; b) I think using a string Subject and grouping on that is doomed to failure - think about it - many Subjects could be the same. You should use an integer and assign a new number to each new thread. Good luck.

Comment: I tried grouping the messages, but messagas with the same subject but other participants where grouped together. But now I use another solution: I have created a parent table "conversations", the messages are assigned to a conversation. This makes it a way easier to handle the messaging system.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...  I"m not sure I understand the question fully yet.

```
Select A.ID, A.Sender, A.Recipient, A.Subject
FROM tableName A
LEFT JOIN tableName B
  on A.Sender=B.Recipient 
 AND A.Subject=B.Subject
Where Sender.ID = USERLOGGEDIN OR B.Recipient = USERLOGGEDIN
ORDER By Subject, ID
```

Comment: I am testing with this, but I think thats a great basis, thanks! I think you have made a mistake in the Where clause, did you mean: "Where A.Sender = USERLOGGEDIN [...]"?